# Date Picker copy field value to another field

Tags: jquery-ui

Using date picker if the users fills out the start date field how to I make the end date field copy that same value?

```
$('#sdate').datepicker({
 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true ,
 firstDay: 1,
  onSelect : function(){
     document.getElementById('edate').value = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', '#sdate');  
}
});

$('#edate').datepicker({
 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true ,
 firstDay: 1
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your onSelect function to:

```
onSelect: function () {
    $('#edate').val(this.value);
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xyp7khfe/)**