# How to set a input tag values automatically based on another input tag value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Hi In my form I have two input fields of date type, I want to set the second input value same as first one automatically, How can I solve this?

Comment: please show us a snippet of what you have tried up to this point

Comment: you can use clone() from  jquery https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón - I do not think clone is useful here. An on keyup or similar

Comment: First clone, second put custom values

Comment: He has TWO input fields in the form. Why clone?

Comment: Another duplicate for datepicker: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565153/date-picker-copy-field-value-to-another-field

Answer (score 0):

use jquery to put the value of first input field in the 2nd as the value of input1 is changed

```
$("#InputId1").keyup(function(){
    $("#InputId2").val(this.value);
});
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply,

Comment: Here is my code 
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
           
   $("#datetimepicker").keyup(function(){
     $("#autofilldate").val(this.value);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="datetimepicker" type="datetime-local" >
<input id = "autofilldate" type="datetime-local" >
</body>

Comment: because you are using datetimepicker so use `change` event beside `keyup` like $("#InputId1").change(function(){
    $("#InputId2").val(this.value);
});